# How to Select only UNIQUE rows in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, select, distinct

I have a table as in sample below

```
   | C1  | C2  | C3 | C4 |
r1 | a   | b   | c  | 1  |
r2 | a   | b   | c  | 2  |
r3 | c   | s   | d  | 3  |
r4 | c   | w   | w  | 4  |
r5 | c   | r   | w  | 5  |
```

Here if we concatenate C1,C2 and C3 columns we see that r1 and r2 rows have same values (C4 is different). I want to Select such that r1 and r2 are dropped and only r3,r4 and r5 are selected.

Distinct cannot work since C4 is Unique and 'Group By' will retain one of the row.

I want an output as follows

```
   | C1  | C2  | C3 | C4 |
r3 | c   | s   | d  | 3  |
r4 | c   | w   | w  | 4  |
r5 | c   | r   | w  | 5  |
```

Comment: `select * from (select t.*, count(*) over(partition by c1, c2, c3) as c from t) x where c = 1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `group by` and filter the groups by their `count` via `having`:

```
select C1, C2, C3, min(C4) as C4
from yourtable
group by C1, C2, C3
having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: Incomplete grouping. May fail. Add any aggregate function (for example, ANY_VALUE).

Comment: @Akina it shouldn't fail AFAIK because we only select groups of single elements and filter out any group where the rule would fail. But I did not test this and I might be wrong. Edited the answer to make it bullet-proof

Comment: You add MIN() - now everything is correct. W/o this function the query will fail if ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode is enabled which is default setting for version 8+

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you. The code worked perfectly as requested. Have a good day !!

Comment: @MohitS happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select c1, c2, c3 from (
  select t.*, count(*) over(partition by c1, c2, c3) as c from t
) x where c = 1
```

Result:

```
 c1  c2  c3 
 --- --- -- 
 c   r   w  
 c   s   d  
 c   w   w
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OYgPQgFA).